# Shehecheyanu upon affixing mezuzah

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, shehecheyanu

The Rambam writes in Sefer Ahava - Hilchos Berachos - Halacha 9:

That Shehecheyanu is recited for every mitzvah that involves acquisition of property: I.e. Mezuzot.

> ט כל מצוה שהיא מזמן לזמן כגון שופר וסוכה ולולב ומקרא מגילה ונר חנוכה. וכן כל מצוה ומצוה שהיא קניין לו כגון ציצית ותפילין ומזוזה ומעקה. וכן מצוה שאינה תדירה ואינה מצוייה בכל עת שהרי היא דומה למצוה שהיא מזמן לזמן. כגון מילת בנו ופדיון הבן מברך עליה בשעת עשייתה שהחיינו. ואם לא בירך על סוכה ולולב וכיוצא בהם שהחיינו בשעת עשייה מברך עליהן שהחיינו בשעה שיצא ידי חובתו בהן וכן כל כיוצא בהן:

And English translation from Chabad.org

> Halacha 9
>   The blessing shehecheyanu is recited:
>   [before] fulfilling every mitzvah that we are obligated to fulfill only at a specific time - e.g., shofar, sukkah, lulav, reading the Megillah, and [lighting] Chanukah candles,
>   [before fulfilling] every mitzvah that involves the acquisition of property - e.g., tzitzit, tefillin, and a guardrail - and
>   [before fulfilling] every mitzvah that we are obligated to fulfill infrequently - for this resembles a mitzvah we are obligated to fulfill only at a specific time - e.g., circumcising one's son and redeeming him.

Does this apply for every instance of getting a New mezuzah? I had not heard or seen people reciting Shehecheyanu upon affixing mezuzot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and can tell from a few sources, in general shehecheyanu is NOT said for mezuzah. However, if the mezuzah is being affixed ready for entry into a *new* house, then many say it should be said, but some prefer also to wear a new garment/eat a new fruit and bless once to cover all. 
http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%91_%D7%94

http://soferstam.co.il/content.aspx?PageId=53&lang=he

http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=106028